# referencing an image from android layout not working

Tags: android, android-imageview

I simply try to reference an image from my res/drawable folder from my ImageView in my simple layout as the picture shows.

There is no reference ?!? Can someone help me howto reference correct ?

[image]

Comment: yes I did a clean and then rebuild.

Comment: I know you said u clean and then rebuild. But did you try Invalidate cache and restart?

Comment: I'll try, thank you for helping.